# RegEx to only match single occurence of a keyword

Tags: regex

I'm having a hard time trying to compose a RegEx to meet my specific requirements.

These are:

1. Match keyword and capture the date that follows
2. If keyword is not present capture nothing
3. If keyword is present more than once, capture nothing

Keyword:

```
 LT circa
```

Example Text:

```
Metall-Notierung 464,95 EUR 100 KG
* LT circa 21.04.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm
* LT circa 17.05.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm
Zolltarifnummer 80464995
```

Expected Result:

```
NULL
```

Example Text:

```
Metall-Notierung 464,95 EUR 100 KG
* LT circa 17.05.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm
Zolltarifnummer 80464995
```

Expected Result:

```
17.05.2020
```

Beeing a Newbie to RegEx these are the things I have tried so far on a simplified subject:

```
This test is a test and nothing else

(.*test.*test.*)?(?(1)(a^):(test.*))
```

...as you might expect, it would be naive to think that this could work.

Experts anyone?

Edit:

I checked using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and NUnit

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test.RegExpressions.Tests
{
   [TestFixture]
   public class SpecialRegexTests
   {
      [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCaseClass), nameof(TestCaseClass.TestCases))]
      public int MatchTest(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions regexOptions)
      {
         return new Regex(pattern, regexOptions).Matches(input).Count;
      }
   }

   public static class TestCaseClass
   {
      private static readonly string S0 = new StringBuilder()
         .AppendLine("Metall - Notierung 464,95 EUR 100 KG")
         .AppendLine("* LT circa 21.04.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm")
         .AppendLine("* LT circa 17.05.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm")
         .AppendLine("Zolltarifnummer 80464995")
         .ToString();

      private static readonly string S1 = new StringBuilder()
         .AppendLine("Metall - Notierung 464,95 EUR 100 KG")
         .AppendLine("* LxT circa 21.04.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm")
         .AppendLine("* LT circa 17.05.2020 2 x 500 M Einwegtrommel 400x 150x 404mm")
         .AppendLine("Zolltarifnummer 80464995")
         .ToString();

      private const string R0 = @"^(?:(?!.*LT circa).+\n)*(?:(?!LT circa).)*LT circa\s+(\d\d\.\d\d.\d{4})(?!(?:.+\n)*.*LT circa)";

      private const string R1 = @"(?s)^(?!(?:.*LT circa){2}).*LT circa\s*\K\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}";

      private const string R2 = @"(?s)^(?!(?:.*LT circa){2}).*LT circa\s*(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})";

      public static IEnumerable TestCases
      {
         get
         {
            yield return new TestCaseData(S0, R0, RegexOptions.None).Returns(0);
            yield return new TestCaseData(S1, R0, RegexOptions.None).Returns(1);

            yield return new TestCaseData(S0, R1, RegexOptions.None).Returns(0);
            yield return new TestCaseData(S1, R1, RegexOptions.None).Returns(1);
            
            yield return new TestCaseData(S0, R2, RegexOptions.None).Returns(0);
            yield return new TestCaseData(S1, R2, RegexOptions.None).Returns(1);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Except for `R1` which uses the `\K` all of them pass the test.

I will update my question as soon as I have more info on the Regex Flavor in use.

Worth to mention, that none of these worked in the Software, which may or may not be a matter of RegEx options I don't have control over.

Comment: This actually sounds like a task for code rather than RegEx. Simply use whatever `find` method your language provides to get a first "match", then check whether there is a second match after that by calling `find` again, using the first match position as an offset.

Comment: @LMD Good point, but I'm limited to RegEx only...

Comment: And how limited is your RegEx? Is it PCRE2, which Wiktor makes use of? Bear in mind that these advanced RegEx implementations often have horrible performance. Can you use multiple regular expressions?

Comment: @LMD This Software conceptually allows for two Expresssions. The first on is used to point to the line in question, contained in a larger block of text. The second expression is used to filter that line for the disired information i.e. the data value. I fear the implementation is the .NET flavour RegEx Engine as a quick test with Wiktor Stribiżew s solution did not match when it should. I mailed to the dev team to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)(?<=^(?!(?:.*LT circa){2}).*LT circa\s*)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3p1vpp/3). The date regex can be enhanced, but the main point is the pattern around it.

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - `s` flag making `.` match any characters
- `(?<=` - start of the positive lookbehind:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?!(?:.*LT circa){2})` - fail the match if there are two occurrences of `LT circa` anywhere in the string
  - `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
  - `LT circa` - the keyword
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `)` - end of the positive lookbehind
- `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}` - date like pattern. `(?:0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\.\d{4}(?!\d)` can be a bit more precise pattern for an arbitrary *dd/MM/yyyy* date (without leap year support).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your effort, and I'd mark this as an answer in a sec. But I feel that my question needs to be a bit more precise about the RegEx flavour in use. I hope to have an update on this soon.

Comment: @SixTimeUser If your regex flavor does not support `\K` you can use `(?s)^(?!(?:.*LT circa){2}).*LT circa\s*(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})`, capturing group instead, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3p1vpp/2). Then extract the group value once you obtain the match.

Comment: could the last one be rewritten to have the data in the match?

Comment: @SixTimeUser Yes, `(?s)(?<=^(?!(?:.*LT circa){2}).*LT circa\s*)\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3p1vpp/3)).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this regex with negative look-aheads. It is slightly longer but will be more efficient than using `DOTALL` mode:

```sh
^(?:(?!.*LT circa).+\n)*(?:(?!LT circa).)*LT circa\s+(\d\d\.\d\d.\d{4})(?!(?:.+\n)*.*LT circa)
```

[.NET RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWgNQI/1)

Comment: Please met me know if this works out then I will add more explanation

Comment: please see my first edit above

Comment: I have looked at the edited question. So this regex did work for you in unit testing right?